# How to use iota_view for custom IntLike types?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges, iota

I would like to use `std::ranges::iota_view` for a custom data type that is "int" like in the same way I would use `std::ranges::iota_view` for an `int`.  I couldn't figure out how to adjust the code based on gcc's error messages, which are posted below:

```
#include <ranges>
#include <limits>

struct IntLike {
    IntLike(int val = {}) : m_val{val} {}
    operator int() const { return m_val; }
    IntLike& operator++() { ++m_val; return *this; }
    IntLike operator++(int) { IntLike ret = *this; ++m_val; return ret; }
    friend auto operator <=>(IntLike lhs, IntLike rhs) = default;

    int m_val;
};

namespace std {
    template<>
    struct iterator_traits<IntLike> {
        using difference_type = IntLike;
    };
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::same_as<std::iter_difference_t<int>, int>);
    static_assert(std::same_as<std::iter_difference_t<IntLike>, IntLike>);
    std::ranges::iota_view(0, 2);
    std::ranges::iota_view(IntLike{0}, IntLike{2});
    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
<source>:26:50: error: class template argument deduction failed:
   26 |     std::ranges::iota_view(IntLike{0}, IntLike{2});
      |                                                  ^
<source>:26:50: error: no matching function for call to 'iota_view(IntLike, IntLike)'
In file included from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/ranges:617:7: note: candidate: 'template<class _Winc, class _Bound> iota_view(typename std::ranges::iota_view<_Winc, _Bound>::_Iterator, typename std::ranges::iota_view<_Winc, _Bound>::_Sentinel)-> std::ranges::iota_view<_Winc, _Bound> requires !(same_as<_Winc, _Bound>) && !(same_as<_Bound, std::unreachable_sentinel_t>)'
  617 |       iota_view(_Iterator __first, _Sentinel __last)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/ranges:617:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:26:50: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_Winc'
```

Answer (score 1):

The first template parameter `W` of `iota_view` requires it to model `weakly_incrementable`, which requires that its difference type must be *signed-integer-like* type, which includes signed integer type and signed *integer-class* type. The latter is an implementation-defined type with integer behavior, which cannot be defined by the user.

Since the difference type of `IntLike` is `IntLike`, which is not a *signed-integer-like* type, the constraint is not satisfied.

The simplest workaround is to define the `difference_type` of `IntLike` as `ptrdiff_t` which has enough width to accommodate the subtracted value of the maximum and minimum values of `int`.

```
namespace std {
    template<>
    struct iterator_traits<IntLike> {
        using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is non-trivial and, even when it works, it is highly limited.

The first problem is [the constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view). The constructor you are *trying* to use is the one that takes the starting point and the boundary condition. However, this constructor is *deliberately prevented* from using class template argument deduction through the use of `std::type_identity_t`. Instead, an explicit deduction guide is used.

However, this guide requires that the types in question are ["integer-like"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/weakly_incrementable#Integer-like_types). And it is *not possible* for user-code to create a type that is "integer-like"; only implementations can create classes that are "integer-like". So this deduction guide never applies.

That's why the compiler thinks you're trying to pass a pair of iterators.

Now, you can bypass the deduction guide by specifying the types directly (though you'll never be able to use `views::iota`, since it always uses the guides). But even if you do, your type must conform to a bunch of concepts: weakly_incrementable, [__WeaklyEqualityComparableWith](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/equality_comparable), [advanceable&decrementable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view/iterator), and probably a few others. You'll also need to provide an iota-diff-t for your type.

Overall... it's probably not worth the effort. It would be a much better use of your time to take a regular `iota` range and apply a `views::transform` to convert each integer to the actual type you desire. Like `views::iota(...) | views::transform([](int i) { return IntLike(i);})`.

Comment: The guide doesn't require integer-like.